# How to prevent changes from services

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm using **Feathers.js** with **Mongoose** and I want to create a field that cannot be changed by the services.

```
// account-model.js - A mongoose model
//
// See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html
// for more of what you can do here.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-type-email');

module.exports = function(app) {
  const mongooseClient = app.get('mongooseClient');

  const recovery = new mongooseClient.Schema({
    token: { type: String, required: true }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  const account = new mongooseClient.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    surname: { type: String, require: true },
    phone: { type: String, require: true },
    email: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email, required: true, unique: true },
    birth: { type: Date, required: true },
    gender: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    address2: { type: String, required: false },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    postcode: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    status: { type: String, required true }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  return mongooseClient.model('account', account);
};
```

No one can make a post at `/account/<id>` and change the field `status`.
This field should only be changed when internally. When some approval service request.

How can I implement this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [Feathers hooks](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html). When accessed externally, in a [service method](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html) call [params.provider](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#paramsprovider) will be set so you can check for it and remove the field from `data` if it is:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return async context => {
    if(context.params.provider) {
      delete context.data.status;
    }
  }
}
```

This hook will be a `before` hook for the `create`, `update` and `patch` method.